# CAShapeLayer class's method "layer" is not available in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

In Objective C, below code works.

```
CAShapeLayer  *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
```

I'm trying to convert the same in swift. But, error throws says CAShapeLayer is does not have a member named "layer"

```
var shapeLayer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer().layer
```

Or

```
CAShapeLayer().layer
```

Any alternative to get layer?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think CAShapeLayer() already returns an instance of CAShapeLayer so this

```
  var shapeLayer : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    //customize your layer
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    self.layer.insertSublayer(shape, atIndex: 0)
```

should work.

Answer (score 5):

The equivalent of

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
```

in Swift is just

```
var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
```

Then you can do

```
shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
...
```